# How to use JQuery selectors on a HTML String?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.get(url, function(data){}
```

This jQuery function returns a string with the code of the page 'url'.

How can I use the jQuery selectors on it to extract the tags informations that I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your data with div (for including the outer most element also to extract the tags) and than use find

```
$("<div>" + data + "</div>").find('div')
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's valid HTML, you can just wrap it in jQuery and use it as you normally would :

```
$.get(url, function(data){
    $(data).find('div');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(data).find('div');
```

you can use this